# wp term relationships error

Tags: database

I have been having some issues with a site saying error establishing a database connection. I have restarted the database on the server which this fixes the issue but sometimes the first time I do this I will get the error.

[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table ‘./ad_cms/vp_backup_wp_term_relationships’ is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed. If I restart it again this will go away and the site works but what I am trying to figure out is what is vp_backup_wp_term_relationships When I look in my database tables I do not see this one all I see is wp_term_relationships does anyone know what the vp_backup is and why I would be having this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Going off of just `vp_backup`, do you have any plugins installed that deal work with terms and/or perform any kind of backups?

Comment: I do have Vault Press running on this site doing backups. I am thinking the vp_backup could stand for Vault Press but can't find any information on this. Has anyone that uses Vault Press seen this before ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has this same issue it is a Vault Press table and they said you can fix this by connecting by SSH